# When use Scanner for input value to array smallest number not found

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

**With Scanner :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputArrayFromScanner {

    private static Scanner keyIn;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        keyIn = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
        int inNum = keyIn.nextInt();
        int [] arrNum = new int [inNum];
        int maxNum = arrNum[0];
        int minNum = arrNum[0];
        int  average = 0;
        int total = 0;
        for (int count : arrNum){
            System.out.print ("> ");
            arrNum[count] = keyIn.nextInt();
            if (arrNum[count] > maxNum)
                maxNum = arrNum[count];
            else if (arrNum[count] < minNum)
                minNum = arrNum[count];
            total += arrNum[count];
            average = total/arrNum.length;
        }
        System.out.print("\tBigest Number is:"+maxNum);
        System.out.print("\tSmallest Number is:"+minNum);
        System.out.print("\tPlus of Numbers is:"+total);
        System.out.println("\tAverage Of Numbers is:"+average);


    }

}
```

**Without scanner**

```
public class MinAndMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arrNum = {10,12,80,6,5};
        int minNum = arrNum [0];
        int maxNum = arrNum [0];
        for (int count = 0; count < arrNum.length; count++ ){
            if (arrNum[count] < minNum)
                minNum = arrNum[count];
            else if (arrNum[count] > maxNum)
                maxNum = arrNum[count];
        } 
       System.out.print ("\tSmallest Number is "+minNum);
       System.out.print ("\tBigest Number is "+maxNum);
    }

}
```

Whats is the problem ?

Comment: Whats problem ????? please tell.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet you are iterating over the array values with the enhanced for loop :

```
for (int count : arrNum)
```

You should be iterating over the array indices :

```
for (int count = 0; count < arrNum.length; count++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some logic mistake

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputArrayFromScanner {

    private static Scanner keyIn;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        keyIn = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
        int inNum = keyIn.nextInt();
        int [] arrNum = new int [inNum];
        int  average = 0;
        int total = 0;

        for (int count = 0;count<inNum;count++){
            arrNum[count] = keyIn.nextInt();
        }

        int maxNum = arrNum[0];
        int minNum = arrNum[0];

        for (int count = 0; count < arrNum.length; count++ ){
            if (arrNum[count] < minNum)
                minNum = arrNum[count];
            else if (arrNum[count] > maxNum)
                maxNum = arrNum[count];
            total += arrNum[count];
            average = total/arrNum.length;
        } 

        System.out.print("\tBigest Number is:"+maxNum);
        System.out.print("\tSmallest Number is:"+minNum);
        System.out.print("\tPlus of Numbers is:"+total);
        System.out.println("\tAverage Of Numbers is:"+average);


    }

}
```

Try this.